# Markowitz Model Invests in Everything

Tags: optimization, matlab, finance, cvx

I'm trying to create portfolios using real life stock market data from the past, to test real life performance of Markowitz portfolio optimization model. Solving through CVX, however, gives me the most weird portfolios where the it invests in everything and the resulting efficient frontier is not a curve, but a zigzag line.

edit: Here's the input data:

```
0.770385819 1.041085387 0.459646675 1.407991775 1.032964003 1.015192832 1.761284058 0.432529846 1.196856508 1.130865217 0.948489011 1.130973958 1.021932454 1.119256276 1.090071648 1.070024263 0.898895476 0.94323697  1.07892532  0.969909847 1.427561837 0.952085375 0.911283811 1.218244825 0.732480413 1.25540862  1.367107712 0.931140812 1.185658681 0.868207764 1.014347682 1.478019669 1.86267166  1.007992203 1.132348209 0.951148514 1.008848925 0.835203173 1.568876745 0.814207457 1.008956842 0.924991843 1.091709856 0.459646675 1.251518105 1.241371696 0.902728017 0.851700526 1.23548996  1.340598122;
    1.563231801 1.160694749 1.295086356 1.102851533 1.658395418 1.441289332 1.131956592 0.441946506 1.429396335 1.168607239 1.112126107 1.079003599 1.097335615 1.34966378  1.186228482 1.619232426 1.043895898 1.258081655 1.442456662 1.071825205 0.977722772 1.149757902 1.160316757 1.245202657 1.483468401 1.207680015 1.428717458 1.468165592 1.115104134 1.504980529 1.179700146 1.137373204 2.054959786 1.325712628 0.885426498 1.300327201 1.358178726 1.392186705 2.588573659 2.686215908 1.016398298 1.331078306 1.187699367 1.295086356 1.234122963 1.300353826 1.418989068 1.504121584 1.361842357 2.410075523;
    2.833927266 1.074222841 1.149776806 2.5667894   1.188622645 1.27342918  1.120995734 2.557863666 1.56851897  1.299325173 1.20084143  1.09924957  1.212777332 1.190550724 1.715039578 1.689773913 1.227945996 0.810509236 1.202735818 1.102883208 1.491139241 1.081009384 0.808332936 1.069644246 1.266890108 1.239471924 1.172905087 1.102346128 1.137121269 1.139571095 1.179716604 1.191004623 1.213307241 1.209411945 1.21512834  1.065562602 1.060866403 0.983125018 0.464863672 1.66855076  1.111080906 1.196453819 1.161552216 1.149776806 1.27028591  1.618204209 1.252353924 1.262311919 1.390691261 0.737679682;
    1.503269518 1.64103917  1.32772227  1.01086575  2.476334985 1.435918879 0.826643773 0.767703937 1.206691156 0.98326345  0.965173507 1.600943419 1.14800529  1.137910023 1.035384615 1.052234414 0.916417592 0.910925845 0.963225503 0.888894562 1.405772496 1.155   0.875774931 1.455537213 1.270564643 1.245505029 1.205900058 1.162396583 0.879163835 1.954987817 1.080998944 0.875943724 0.849193548 2.86717459  0.821654933 1.14574944  1.167947175 1.208396908 1.480125546 1.344855794 1.198409593 1.442598391 1.09413377  1.32772227  1.286854078 1.282799117 1.055728237 1.046595974 3.609028312 0.972209445;
    2.027605491 0.975980961 1.523751475 0.60734791  0.954704656 0.948747816 1.152948392 0.555557551 1.327389277 2.006589554 1.130072166 0.988036542 0.974592813 1.085481069 1.51589896  0.770266552 1.075550379 1.17000843  2.37991297  1.374691252 0.963768116 1.033065094 1.207308029 1.03158237  1.27473305  1.323322811 0.995666963 1.701634761 1.197580575 1.796410512 1.34454464  1.414615372 0.908515353 1.074479273 1.892912954 1.215585858 1.260530805 1.946122565 1.054051499 0.464658358 1.258692039 1.415613126 1.363021507 1.523751475 1.224722064 1.193179055 1.770201997 1.155290681 0.999299308 2.09035457;
```

This is the CVX model:

```
RR = [1.15:0.01:1.21];

for i=1:length(RR)
    R = RR(i);
    cvx_begin quiet;
    variable x(length(mu))
    minimize (x'*S*x)
    subject to
     mu'*x >= R;
     e'*x == 1.0000;
     x>= 0;
      x<=0.33
    cvx_end

    xx = [xx x];
    rr = [rr mu'*x];
    stdv = [stdv sqrt(x'*S*x)];

end
```

And here's the output:

```
   Calling SDPT3 4.0: 57 variables, 7 equality constraints
------------------------------------------------------------

 num. of constraints =  7
 dim. of socp   var  =  6,   num. of socp blk  =  1
 dim. of linear var  = 51
*******************************************************************
   SDPT3: Infeasible path-following algorithms
*******************************************************************
 version  predcorr  gam  expon  scale_data
    NT      1      0.000   1        0    
it pstep dstep pinfeas dinfeas  gap      prim-obj      dual-obj    cputime
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 0|0.000|0.000|3.9e+02|1.7e+01|7.3e+03| 1.228178e+01  0.000000e+00| 0:0:00| chol  1  1 
 1|0.947|1.000|2.1e+01|1.0e-01|4.2e+02| 4.638828e+00 -1.233840e+01| 0:0:00| chol  1  1 
 2|0.977|1.000|4.6e-01|1.0e-02|1.9e+01| 7.587821e-02 -9.896742e+00| 0:0:00| chol  1  1 
 3|1.000|1.000|1.8e-07|1.0e-03|2.5e+00| 2.008947e-02 -2.496417e+00| 0:0:00| chol  1  1 
 4|0.961|0.948|1.0e-07|1.5e-04|1.3e-01| 1.434256e-02 -1.174981e-01| 0:0:00| chol  1  1 
 5|0.972|0.422|1.7e-08|8.9e-05|1.1e-01| 5.465703e-03 -1.043929e-01| 0:0:00| chol  1  1 
 6|1.000|0.443|1.0e-08|5.0e-05|8.7e-02| 6.486070e-03 -8.040863e-02| 0:0:00| chol  1  1 
 7|0.684|0.739|3.9e-09|1.3e-05|4.3e-02| 4.102134e-03 -3.888568e-02| 0:0:00| chol  1  1 
 8|0.949|1.000|2.6e-10|1.1e-08|1.0e-02| 3.037969e-04 -1.007127e-02| 0:0:00| chol  1  1 
 9|1.000|1.000|8.5e-11|1.1e-09|2.5e-03| 9.298042e-05 -2.408280e-03| 0:0:00| chol  1  1 
10|0.979|0.985|1.8e-12|1.3e-10|1.6e-04| 2.714452e-06 -1.545940e-04| 0:0:00| chol  1  1 
11|0.985|0.985|2.5e-14|1.3e-11|2.4e-06| 4.039800e-08 -2.340381e-06| 0:0:00| chol  1  1 
12|0.995|0.995|5.9e-15|1.1e-12|3.9e-08| 4.608065e-10 -3.805504e-08| 0:0:00| chol  1  1 
13|1.000|0.997|4.6e-15|1.0e-12|7.4e-10| 7.917000e-12 -7.267619e-10| 0:0:00|
  stop: max(relative gap, infeasibilities) < 1.49e-08
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 number of iterations   = 13
 primal objective value =  7.91700039e-12
 dual   objective value = -7.26761875e-10
 gap := trace(XZ)       = 7.36e-10
 relative gap           = 7.36e-10
 actual relative gap    = 7.35e-10
 rel. primal infeas (scaled problem)   = 4.59e-15
 rel. dual     "        "       "      = 1.00e-12
 rel. primal infeas (unscaled problem) = 0.00e+00
 rel. dual     "        "       "      = 0.00e+00
 norm(X), norm(y), norm(Z) = 7.4e-01, 6.1e-09, 3.2e+00
 norm(A), norm(b), norm(C) = 1.3e+01, 2.9e+00, 4.2e+00
 Total CPU time (secs)  = 0.37  
 CPU time per iteration = 0.03  
 termination code       =  0
 DIMACS: 5.9e-15  0.0e+00  1.3e-12  0.0e+00  7.3e-10  7.4e-10
-------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------
Status: Solved
Optimal value (cvx_optval): +7.91702e-12

     3

    0.0086
    0.0143
    0.0073
    0.0186
    0.0125
    0.0115
    0.1894
    0.0055
    0.0197
    0.0269
    0.0117
    0.0179
    0.0130
    0.0136
    0.0198
    0.0095
    0.0109
    0.0098
    0.0208
    0.0130
    0.0534
    0.0115
    0.0100
    0.0182
    0.0087
    0.0259
    0.0193
    0.0123
    0.0169
    0.0148
    0.0143
    0.0485
    0.0204
    0.0178
    0.0270
    0.0114
    0.0122
    0.0119
    0.0077
    0.0047
    0.0155
    0.0133
    0.0165
    0.0073
    0.0237
    0.0237
    0.0124
    0.0089
    0.0472
    0.0101
```

Is there a reason for this? I checked almost everything to find a connection, but I failed. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you have any regularization in your optimization? Is it mentioned in his method?

Comment: @mathreadler I don't think so. This problem only happens with 4 of the 12 datasets I use though, so I doubt it's about the optimization itself.

Comment: What is your risk measure?

Comment: @Elsa this one is not the risk adjusted version. it's trying to minimize the variance for 1.22 rate of return.

Comment: What is your input ? How can the output be interpreted without knowing the data and the model ? Please explain.

Comment: @callculus i'm sorry, adding it right away.

Comment: @enlightunderwood  ok, if there are no positivity constraints, you could go for a closed form solution instead of using an optimizer. Anyways, is the covariance matrix well defined and of full rank?

Comment: @Elsa I... think so? When I check from MATLAB it shows the rank as 4. I don't know how to check being well defined :/

Comment: @enlightunderwood so you can only have 4 securities. If I read your input correctly, it seems that you have many more stocks but only a few observed returns per stock. If so, this will result in a singular covariance matrix. If using an estimaed covariance matrix, there must be more returns per stock than nb of stocks.

Comment: @Elsa I get it -- I think. I need more input data for it to work correctly. This is actually a rolling horizon and this and 2 others are the only periods the model does this, and rank is the exact same in the other working ones -- but I tried this one with more data and it worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments, having more stocks than observed returns per stocks results in a singular covariance matrix if this matrix is estimated as follows:

Let $r_t$ be a vector of $N$ returns at time $t$. If we estimate $\mathbf{E}[r_tr_t']$ by
$S:=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T r_tr_t'.$
Then any column $i$ of $S$ is
$\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T r_tr_{i,t}$
with $r_{i,t}$ being the $i$th element of $r_t$. This means that column $i$ is a linear combination of $T$ vectors. Moreover, all columns are linear combinations of the same $T$ vectors.
Hence, the rank of $S$ cannot exceed $min(T,N)$. And so, if $T<N$ this results in a singular covariance matrix.

This potentially transforms a "minimization of a quadratic form"-problem into a (partly) linear optimization problem, probably resulting in a (piecewise) linear Markovitz frontier instead of the usual curved once and which may have multiple solutions.

Sidenote, $S$ is the covariance matrix for demeaned return vectors. However, the rank argument holds true for non demeaned returns.

Comment: thanks so much!